# MLA Background Research Paper: Noting a citation in the text?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, citations, research, mla

I need to write a background research paper on a science fair experiment, but it needs to be formatted in MLA. I looked up some examples of a MLA essay and research paper but there seems to be something that bothers me. At the end of some bit of information or a sentence there seems to be a small word in parenthesis.

### Example

> Batteries don't perform as well in low temperatures.(Best Batteries 71) <-----!!!

I saw this in most of the references I found. There seems to be a similarly worded citation at the end of the paper so I assume that it is telling the reader where the information before the parenthesis came from, but I do not know for sure. If I am correct then is it alright(or uncommon)to cite definitions and how should I note the definition at the end of the sentence? I am not sure about anything because this is my first time writing a MLA formatted paper. I hope you can help me a bit.

Comment: @what Thanks for the help!~ Although I wish you could've worded that nicer I appreciate your concern!~ <3

Comment: @what Your comment is rude and inflammatory. Please be nicer to users.

Comment: @Sugarblob This is being flagged as too-broad and has a few close votes to that effect; it may be closed if additional users vote to close it. Please do stick around and feel free to ask more questions about academic writing.

Comment: @what: OP asked a clear and answerable question. Yes, it's at beginner level - but I don't know his circumstances (it sounds like this task was imposed on OP, and they don't know where to start) and Stack Exchange works _fine_ with beginner questions. Yes, OP should go read the documentation. And so we can answer their question, and point them to the documentation.

Comment: @what, people writing research papers as part of class assignments have presumably received instruction, but I see "science fair" in the question and think of somebody who's *not* an academic, who did something cool for a fair and has been told to write it up in a particular way.  I see a beginner question here, not academic failure.  Thank you for providing the OP with a link for MLA citation.

Comment: Thank you all for your supportive and kind words but don't be so hard on him/her. I was a little clueless too... You guys don't have to worry to much about this~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have understood correctly. From the [Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/):

> In MLA style, referring to the works of others in your text is done by using what is known as **parenthetical citation**. This method involves placing relevant source information in parentheses after a quote or a paraphrase.

They give an example:

> `Wordsworth stated that Romantic poetry was marked by a "spontaneous
>   overflow of powerful feelings" (263).`
>
> `Romantic poetry is characterized by the "spontaneous overflow of
>   powerful feelings" (Wordsworth 263).`
>
> Both citations in the examples above, (263) and (Wordsworth 263), tell
>   readers that the information in the sentence can be located on page
>   263 of a work by an author named Wordsworth. If readers want more
>   information about this source, they can turn to the Works Cited page,
>   where, under the name of Wordsworth, they would find the following
>   information:
>
> `Wordsworth, William. Lyrical Ballads. London: Oxford UP, 1967.`

MLA has an extensive system for providing citations that are clear and well-defined; you really need to [dig into the details](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/675/01/) and get a better sense of what's expected of you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot! Thank you for your time, Standback! <3